# How to use selected spinner value to perform calculation?

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I am working on the app where I want to implement spinner with Gender choice for Male and Female. Once the value is selected the this value should be used in the calculation as at the screen below. I tested spinner with Toast.maketext and it works, I also tested the Calculate BMR part of the code with using text field and it works. What I am trying to do is now to pass that selected string from the spinner which if in case M it will execute first block of code if they chose F the app will execute second block of code which is for female. 
How do I pass the string from spinner that i am storing int gen and use it in the CalculateBMR code block?

[image]

Comment: why not create a field variable and update its value when the spinner's onItemSelected is called.

It will also help if you can share your actual code and not a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Since you are creating a local variable gen it's loosing its value after you are selecting the gender here,

```
@Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String gen = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        }
```

I am assuming that you are doing it inside an activity so create the variable in activity level like,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String gen;
}
```

Then inside onItemSelected do like below

```
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            gen = adapterView.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

        }
```

But you need to make sure that spinner has a default value without that string gen will throw exception.

Comment: Padmini S -  Thank you so much. Your suggestion worked like charm. :-)